# How to update the view on property change of objects in ObservableMap?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have an observable map, which maps arbitrary objects (say another maps) to their id's. When I make changes to these objects, the objects should be updated in the view, too. However, I didn't get it to work. Here is my setup so far:

**myexample.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="my-example">
  <script type="application/dart" src="myexample.dart"></script>
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <template repeat="{{ entry in map.values }}">
          <li>{{ entry }}</li>
        </template>
    </ul>
    <button on-click="{{change}}">Change</button>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**myexample.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('my-example')
class MyExample extends PolymerElement {
  @observable Map<int, String> map = toObservable({'123': {'name': 'XYZ', 'size': 12}});

  MyExample.created() : super.created() {
    map.changes.listen((_) => notifyPropertyChange(#map, 1, 0));
  }

  void change() {
    var object = map['123']
    object['size'] = 100;
    map.notifyChange(new MapChangeRecord('123', null, object));
  }
}
```

On clicking the 'Change'-Button, the object with id '123' is updated in the map, but isn't updated in view. Has anyone an idea, how to deliver the changes to the view?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <template repeat="{{ entry in map.values }}">
          <li>x{{ entry['name'] }} {{ entry['size']}}</li>
          <template repeat="{{ item in entry.values}}">
            y{{item}}
          </template>
        </template>
      </ul>
      <button on-click="{{change}}">Change</button>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

```dart
@CustomTag('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {

  @observable
  Map map = toObservable({'123': {'name': 'XYZ', 'size': 12}});

    AppElement.created() : super.created();

  void change() {
    var object = map['123']['size'] = 100;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the map to `@observable Map map = toObservable({'123': toObservable({'name': 'XYZ', 'size': 12})});` doesn't work either: The view still remains unmodified.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you address the values more directly it works without any additional support. Seems that just the `toString()` representation generated in your code example doesn't get updated (I have only some vague assumptions why).